# Will the "for" loop not have an effect on something I'm looping over?

Tags: list-manipulation

My title is probably worded horribly, let me explain what I mean. So I essentially have a list of lists, and I want to go through and mark which list indices have a certain property. This is how I have it written out:

```
For[j = 1, j <= Length[list], j++,
 For[k = j + 1, k <= Length[list], k++,
  If[list[[j]][[1]] < list[[k]][[1]] && 
  list[[j]][[2]] < list[[k]][[2]] && 
  list[[j]][[2]] > list[[k]][[1]], Append[bad, j]]]]
```

"bad" is supposed to be an empty list, which afterwards will have a list of the indices I care about. However, after I run this function, "bad" is still an empty list. It works fine if instead of appending, I simply print the indices j, k. Is there a reason for this?

Maybe I should also mention this is what a typical "list" looks like:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}
```

Comment: The simple answer is that `Append` does not rewrite `bad`; you need `AppendTo`. But I will follow up with a longer answer (in a couple of hours when it's lunchtime) to suggest a better approach than the loop-and-append approach. Are you by chance a new Mathematica user coming from Matlab or Fortran? I've noticed that people coming from those languages tend to use that approach a lot.

Comment: Could you express the criterion to select the "bad" components in words? And possibly provide a longer input sample, and the corresponding output you expect? As @Verbeia mentioned, `AppendTo` instead of `Append` is a quick fix, however there are certainly better ways than loops and `AppendTo`, but I have a hard time deciding exactly what your program is intended to do. Consider also that e.g. `list[[j]] [[1]]` can always be written as `list[[j,1]]`, which appears more readable.

Comment: Also consider the possibility of returning elements instead of indices. Mathematica functions are prone to do that.

Comment: How big are the lists you're planning to run this against? Is speed important? Your code will be slow, but will handle long lists, the only answer so far will be slow, and will blow chunks on long lists (you'll chew up RAM). Other than mistakenly using `Append` when you should use `AppendTo` (or directly update `bad` via `Append`), there's nothing intrinsically wrong with your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: @Szabolcs I think, it's rather *this* answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/26956

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Yes, that's right!  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: While the core problem here was the use of `Append`, the actual goal is a subtly hard problem to do efficiently that has application to similar problems/occasional questions. Were there a "reverse a close vote", I'd use it here personally...

Comment: @mathers101: Please see [this meta post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-are-basically-duplicates-of-the-pitfalls-thread). While your particular problem was solved by changing `Append` to `AppendTo`, the general problem itself is rather interesting and has clearly attracted very interesting answers. I'm wondering if you would be willing to edit your title and question with more details about the problem itself, so that we can use this as a reference for future users, and the answers will more closely match the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noted in comments that the simple answer to your question is that `Append` does not rewrite `bad`; you need `AppendTo`.

But here is a more "Mathematica"-like way to consider. Its main disadvantage is that it actually calculates the test for j >= k as well as j < k, and then throws away the result you don't need.

```
Position[UpperTriangularize[
  Outer[(#1[[1]] < #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] && #1[[2]] > #2[[
        1]]) &, list, list, 1], 1], True, {2}]

(*  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}  *)
```

Some things to note about this solution:

- I have used the optional fourth argument of [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) to get Mathematica to see `list` as a vector of elements (that just happen to be lists) rather than treating it as a matrix. The result of the `Outer` function is a matrix of `True` and `False` values.
- I then zero out the ones we don't need using [`UpperTriangularize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpperTriangularize.html), including its second argument, which makes sure the lead diagonal is also zeros.
- Finally, I extract the indices (your `j` and `k`) for which the value is `True` using [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html).  Again note that I've used an option (third) argument to tell Mathematica at what level of the list I should be looking for the `True` values.

I'm sure there are other solutions that other members could provide.

---

**Follow-up**

I suspect the `Outer` construct is the one you are having trouble understanding, so here are some examples to build up to the version I used.

```
list=Range[5];

Outer[(#1<#2)&,list,list]//TableForm

False   True    True    True    True
False   False   True    True    True
False   False   False   True    True
False   False   False   False   True
False   False   False   False   False
```

Now try a matrix

```
list2=RandomInteger[{0,10},{5,2}]
(*{{8,8},{2,0},{5,0},{3,4},{10,6}} *)
```

Here's an example using the fourth argument of `Outer`, to show how it knits together each row, not each element, to create a n-by-n matrix, where n is the length of `list2`.

```
Outer[(#1[[1]]<#2[[2]])&,list2,list2,1]//TableForm
False   False   False   False   False
True    False   False   True    True
True    False   False   False   True
True    False   False   True    True
False   False   False   False   False
```

If I just removed that fourth argument, the command above would record an error because it would then be working on the lowest-level elements of the list `list2`.  So instead I would need to write the following.

```
Outer[(#1<#2)&,list2,list2]
{{{{False,False},{False,False},{False,False},{False,False},{True,False}},
 {{False,False},{False,False},{False,False},{False,False},{True,False}}},
 {{{True,True},{False,False},{True,False},{True,True},{True,True}},
 {{True,True},{True,False},{True,False},{True,True},{True,True}}},
 {{{True,True},{False,False},{False,False},{False,False},{True,True}},
 {{True,True},{True,False},{True,False},{True,True},{True,True}}}, 
 {{{True,True},{False,False},{True,False},{False,True},{True,True}}, 
 {{True,True},{False,False},{True,False},{False,False},{True,True}}}, 
 {{{False,False},{False,False},{False,False},{False,False},{False,False}}, 
 {{True,True},{False,False},{False,False},{False,False},{True,False}}}}
```

The result in that case is a tensor with `Dimensions` `{5, 2, 5, 2}`.

Comment: To answer your question, yeah I'm a new Mathematica user. I haven't really used a math-based programming language before, just Python and C++. To be honest I really don't understand what's happening in this solution, but I'll look it over more and see if I can figure it out

Answer (score 6):

My take, assuming speed matters:

```
fnrO = Module[{r = Range@Length@#, lt = #, p1, c, rr,ll=Length@#},
    rr = Reap[For[j = 1, j < ll, j++,
       lt = Rest@lt;
       p1 = Pick[r[[j + 1 ;;]], BitOr @@ UnitStep[Subtract[#[[j]], Transpose@lt]], 0];
       If[p1 =!= {},c = Tr[BitXor[1, UnitStep[Subtract[lt[[p1 - j, 1]], #[[j, 2]]]]]];
        If[c =!= 0, Sow[{j, c}]]];]];
    If[rr[[2]] === {}, {}, rr[[2, 1]]]] &;
```

On your tiny example:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}};
result = fnrO@list
Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ result
```

> {{2,1}}
>
> {2}

I took the liberty of condensing the output into pairs, first element the index in the list, second element the count found. Using `Join @@ ConstantArray @@@...` on the result returns the same format as your code (i.e., repeated indices when there's more than one "hit").

Quick performance comparison against your code and existing answers (on the cigar lounge squirrel-book, so expect 5-10X faster for all on real hardware), using `RandomInteger[10, {len, 2}]` to generate test cases:

[image]

This is just a quick-n-dirty first pop, my gut tells me there's a clever bottom-up approach that s/b much faster, pondering now...

Comment: You're smoking too much +1

Answer (score 5):

This seems twice as fast as your loop. I don't doubt faster solutions are out there.

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {400, 2}];
f[l1_, l2_, idx_] := Catch[Scan[If[l1[[1]] < #[[1]] < l1[[2]] < #[[2]], Throw[idx]] &, 
                                l2]; Sequence @@ {}]

MapIndexed[f[#1, list[[#2[[1]] + 1 ;;]], #2[[1]]] &, list]
```

Comment: Appears to get different results from OP? His returns repeated indices for multiple "hits" (perhaps to later count or something...)

Comment: @ciao Perhaps. Posting a faster `If[ ]` right now

Comment: Well, +1 in any case, clean...